# pg.Pool is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a google cloud function using [this code](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/sql) and it gives the error TypeError: pg.Pool is not a constructor at exports.postgresDemo I have

```
    {
  "dependencies": {
    "pg": "^2.0.5"
  }
}
```

as the dependencies. I don't know if the error is in  node or cloud functions

Comment: Please post that part of the snippet. Also, have you required pg?

Comment: @SanSolo what snippet? I copied Google's sample code and put in the info for my postgresql database and it gives me that error. Yes I required pg. Thanks for your help

Comment: So the error is at this point? `pgPool = new pg.Pool(pgConfig)`? snippet because that's considered good practice instead of people having to go visit another page. Increases the chances of getting an answer

Comment: I just checked the [documentation](https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling) for the pg package. There the require is not a variable, it is : `const { Pool } = require('pg')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should have been obvious from your dependencies :

```
"dependencies": {
    "pg": "^2.0.5"
  }
}
```

I ran this:

```
const pg = require('pg')
const pool = new pg.Pool()
console.log(pool)
```

and got the expected result. Difference is, in my dependencies, I have :`"pg": "^7.7.1"`. The google example you are using also uses a more recent version of pg. 
I tried to install your version to double check using `npm install pg@2.0.5` but got the error: `npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for pg@2.0.5`
So upgrade pg and it will work

Comment: @Andy Hay is this useful?

Answer (score 3):

For those who want or need to load the npm [`pg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg) package as an **ES6 module** instead:

```
import pg from 'pg';
const { Pool } = pg;

const pool = new Pool({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  user: 'postgres',
  password: '********',
  database: 'postgres',
});
```

Related: [Can I import the node-postgres module (pg) or is it CommonJS only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377103/can-i-import-the-node-postgres-module-pg-or-is-it-commonjs-only)

Comment: weird javascript is weird (and tks.. this worked haha)