# Can I import the node-postgres module (pg) or is it CommonJS only?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules, node-postgres

I have been writing most of my APIs in old-school JavaScript using `const var = require('var').` I am now writing my first API in ES6 syntax including using import rather than require. I always use the node-postgres module `const {Pool} = require('pg')` but when I try to write this as `import {Pool} from 'pg'` I get the error

`SyntaxError: The requested module 'pg' does not provide an export named 'Pool'.`

Similarly, `import Pool from 'pg'` gives me

`TypeError: Pool is not a constructor`

Is there a way to import this as an ES6 module or do I need to find another package for my ES6 postgres connections? I couldn't find any examples online of people using node-postgres with imports.

Answer (score 28):

This should handle that I think.

```
import * as pg from 'pg'
const { Pool } = pg
```

Comment: Your answer and the answer to the question that my question was apparently a duplicate of were both correct/solved my problem, but the other question was a more thorough answer. Thanks!

Comment: If you are using Typescript strict mode, make sure you provide the `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` compiler option

Comment: `const { Pool } = pg.default`

Comment: If you use `import pg from 'pg'` instead of `import * as pg from 'pg'`, you can use `const { Pool } = pg` instead of `const { Pool } = pg.default`

Comment: This gives an error `Property 'Pool' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/home/server/pg")'. const { Pool } = pg`, even with allowSyntheticDefaultImports.