# [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, postgresql, eslint

I have a working api with Node.js and PostgreSQL. When I convert the code to ES6 I get the following error when I running *node index.js* from terminal.

```
node:internal/process/esm_loader:74
internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                          ^
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\node\api\queries' imported from C:\node\api\index.jss
Did you mean to import ../queries.js?
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:258:15)
at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:276:11)
at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:699:10)
at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:810:11)
at Loader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:85:40)
at Loader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:229:28)
at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:51:40)
at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:50:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

I have three files that have had lines changed:

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const db = require('./queries').default
```

converted to:

```
import express from 'express'
import { json, urlencoded } from 'body-parser'
import db from './queries'
```

**queries.js**

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool
```

conerted to:

```
import { Pool } from 'pg'
```

**package.json** - I have added:

```
"type": "module",
```

What else do I need to do to fix this error?

Comment: The answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377103/can-i-import-the-node-postgres-module-pg-or-is-it-commonjs-only